# Croesus and the wise Solon

Tags: riddle

The riddle is about reading this text so it rhymes:

**To Croesus said the wise man Solon

by the sight of all his treasures:

First when dead and in the dark

you will find peace!**

But! You may not change any words, you may not change the words positions, you may not translate it to another language.
The shown text should be made to rhyme with no changes whatsoever.

Hint:

> Read everything.

For the curious ones (has nothing to do with the riddle itself):
Croesus was the king of Lydia, and very rich.
Solon was a philosopher, and acknowledged for his wisdom.

Comment: Can you add words?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You just need to

> pronounce the punctuation. Solon rhymes with colon, and dark rhymes with (exclamation) mark.

Comment: That was fast. Congratulations.